# Lucene.Net bitwise query on bloom-filter

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net, bloom-filter

If in lucene i have a document with a field "bloom" which is a byte array [0 1 0 1 1 1 1] is there a way to perform a query for this document via bitwise operation like, andquery(value:[1 1 1 1 1 1 1], matching:[1 1 1 1 1 1 1]) orquery, notquery etc on the fields.

The basic goal of which is to efficiently encode a large amount of hashes (bloom filter) and query for it.  I am trying to avoid creating 100+ bool fields that would have to match in a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to encode a filter [0 1 0 1 1 1 1] to a string '0101111' and use a [wildcard queries](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Wildcard%20Searches) for searching for several hashes '0?0???1'. Also, I think in your use case will be useful a [fuzzy searching](https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches), basing on the Levenshtein distance which will take into account number of different element in strings.